# Select all option from select and display each option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display all options in individual "li"s under the select box when a user hits "Select All". I feel like I'm missing something simple. Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/m5adns2y/2/

```
enter code here
```

As you can see, when you hit the button, each result is "[object HTMLOptionElement]". I need the text.

Changing onTeam[i] to onTeam.text()[i] isn't helping either.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You were close to the right page with the `onTeam.text()[i]`, but you need to refer to the array element, then the text property like `onTeam[i].text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.html()` method provided by [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/html/). or `.innerHTML` property of a [DOM Element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Change

```
onTeam[i]
```

To

```
$(onTeam[i]).html()
```

or

```
onTeam[i].innerHTML
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/m5adns2y/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's much simplied and straight jquery solution.

```
    $('#selectAllTeamMembers').click(function() {

   $(".add-team-member option").each(function(index)
   {
    if(index == 0)
     return;
    $('.assigned-users-list').append('<li><div class="tag-list-item"><span>' + $(this).text() + '</span> <i class="fa fa-times-circle" data-idx="' + index  + '"></i></div></li>');
    });

     $(this).prop("disabled",true);
  });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/m5adns2y/7/